# Insert Indirectly Into a Naming Table?

Tags: java, database, jpa

Let's consider this diagram

[image: A Genre table and Track table, where track has a FK on Genre and Genre only consists of the PK 'name']

With this JPA snippet of the Track class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "track")
public class Track {
    @Id
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "genre")
    private String genre;

    /* Getters, setters, etc */
}
```

And the database schema

```
/** Liquibase */
<changeSet id="1" author="SoulBeaver">
    <createTable tableName="genre">
        <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(1024)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <createTable tableName="track">
        <column name="id" type="UUID">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="genre" type="VARCHAR(1024)" />
    </createTable>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="track" baseColumnNames="genre" constraintName="genre_fk"
                             referencedTableName="genre"
                             referencedColumnNames="name" />
</changeSet>
```

Now, when I try to persist a track, which has been given a track.setGenre("Rock"); I get a RuntimeError stating that the key does not exist in Genre.

Is there any way I can avoid having to create the Genre class, persisting the Genre first, and finally persisting the Track?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the FKey Constraint works in such a way that if you try to insert a value in child table with FKey value not present in your parent table, it will fail. This is not specific to JPA. It is how relational DB is designed.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of a @ManyToMany relation in Java. It lets you relate two tables with each other while never having to explicitly call or set the joining table at all. Perhaps I was hoping for some JPA (or similar) functionality, that could perform this in the context of my question. However, what you say is true and maybe what I'm suggesting isn't feasible at all.

Comment: One workaround you can possibly do is not storing the genre initially in a track and later update it once you have stored the actual track.